# Excluding selective file from run inside bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run below gnuplot command to generate graph from gpl file.

```
gnuplot gplfile0.gpl 
gnuplot gplfile1.gpl 
gnuplot gplfile2.gpl 
gnuplot gplfile3.gpl 
gnuplot gplfile4.gpl 
gnuplot gplfile5.gpl 
gnuplot gplfile6.gpl 
..
..
..
..
```

I have a parent `gplfile.gpl` which help to generate all require `gplfile*.gpl` with unique content. I don't want to remove or move or delete parent file form given folder.

I have written a bash shell script to run above commands.

**run_script.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Generating the images using gnu plot"

date 

shopt -s extglob
rm -rf *.png

for f in *gpl
do
    gnuplot $f
done
```

I am able to generate output from all `gplfile*.gpl` file. But I want to **exclude** parent `gplfile.gpl` from running .

How I can **exclude** running parent `gplfile.gpl` file from the bash shell script.

Is there any command in the bash shell script to **exclude** the specific file from run.

Comment: soooo `for f in *[0-9].gpl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `extglob` on then.

```
for file in !(gplfile).gpl; do echo gnuplot "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a better matching glob. For example match the digit:

```
for f in *[0-9].gpl
```

or really, just exclude it:

```
for f in *.gpl; do
   if [[ "$f" == gplfile.gpl ]]; then continue; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the shell globbing with `find` and loop over that instead. If you need to exclude just a *single* file, it is as simple as

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.gpl" ! -name gplfile.gpl); do echo $f; done
./gplfile9.gpl
./gplfile8.gpl
./gplfile0.gpl
./gplfile1.gpl
..
..
./gplfile4.gpl
```